# How to find which variables are retained in scikit learn

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, scikit-learn

I am running some algorithms in scikit. Like Currently I use RandomisedLasso. But this question pertain to any ml algo in scikit.

My initial training data is 149x56. Now here is what I do:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import RandomizedLasso
est_rlasso = RandomizedLasso(max_iter=1000)
# Running Randomised Lasso
x=est_rlasso.fit_transform(tourism_X,tourism_Y)
x.shape

>>> (149x36).
```

So if you see it gives out 36 best features to be retained out of 56 initially and transforms the dataset from 149x56 to 149x36. But the problem is which 36 features did it retain? The biggest problem with scikit is that it strips off the variable headers. So now I am left clueless which features did this algorithm keep and which one it removed as the final X has no header to cross-check.

THis is common across any ml algorithm implementation in scikit. How does one overcome this? Like if I need to find which variables it gave as significant or if I am running a Regression model then the coefficient stand for which variables as I might have used Onehotencoder to transform categorical variables and then it would change the var order from original.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3):

From the docs

> get_support([indices])    Return a mask, or list, of the features/indices
>   selected.

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RandomizedLasso.html

Comment: Thanks. This helps in the Randomised Lasso case. But what about others? Like I am also running a Random ForestRegressor , it doesn't have something like this get_support to tell me which features are selected. All it has is a feature_importance attribute but it doesn't tell me which features are getting selected after doing fit_transform

Comment: There is currently no method there, but you can use the feature_importances and threshold them as described in the docstring of transform. We are trying to improve the interface here: https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/pull/4242